# Using case-insensitive regular expressions in Chrome extensions

Tags: regex, google-chrome-extension

I am new to regular expressions (and Chrome extensions).
I am trying to check if an image is loaded in Chrome. Specifically, I am checking if the url ends with PNG or JPG, but I cannot get it to be case-insensitive.

Here is the code:

new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher
({

```
pageUrl: { urlMatches: '\.(JPG|PNG)$/i'},
```

})

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your string is missing the first slash `/`.

Comment: Uhm, see the [re2 syntax documentation](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt): `(?flags)`. Also, you need double \\ because it's inside a string. Alternatively you can use a literal regexp and extract the string using its `.source` property.

Comment: @Ivan That's not needed. urlMatches is a regular expression by definition.

Comment: @wOxxOm I am aware of the documentation. What I am unable to figure out is how to add the case-insensitive flag (i) to make the string case-insensitive.

Comment: I think wOxxOm is saying the answer is `'\\.(?i)(JPG|PNG)$'`. At least that would work in many other languages, and it agrees with the "Flags" section in the docs. (And your `/` would have been treated as a literal `/`.)

Comment: wOxxOm and @David - Thanks. That worked.

Answer (score 0):

please try with this regexp
/.(JPG|PNG)$/gi